# wordpress title link out

Tags: wordpress

Here is what i do

```
<?php $id=97; $page_data = get_page($id); echo $page_data->post_content;  ?>
```

It's fine, all the data in my page got into the div i want.. fine...

that get me the page tite :

```
<?php $my_id = 7; $post_id_7 = get_post($my_id); $title = $post_id_7->post_title; ?>
```

But that text is a link that link to the singlepost view.... i want to remove the link, just get the text, it's posible with jquery, but i prefer the wp way... is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use your sample code also found at: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post I get *ONLY* the text, not a link to anything. When I do this:

```
<?php
$my_id = 1;
$post_id_7 = get_post($my_id);
$title = $post_id_7->post_title;
echo $title;
?>
```

My only output is "Post Title", not <a href="/post-title">Post Title</a> I'm using WordPress 3.0, perhaps there's a difference between the version you're using?